# TMS320F28379D Flash Sector storing constants

Tags: c, embedded

I am using Ti F28379D C2000 family dual core controller.

The controller has FLASH sectors from A to N.
The executable code will be loaded on sector 'FLASH E size:=7FFF', but i want to use sector FLASH K size :='0x1FFF' as data table which will have constants stored . These constants will be used accordingly in executable running on sector FLASH E.

Problem statement:

How can i create a source file with only constants in "source.c" file which can compile and let me load the file in required sector FLASH K.
Is it possible to have without a main function.

I need to convert this to a Motorola S-record format to load.

any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can write code consisting of data only. But there are other ways, some more convenient than others. Please tell us where the data come from, in what format you have them, and which compiler you are using. For example, GCC has `__attribute__((...))` that can be used to place data or functions in certain sections, and you can allocate these at certain addresses via the linker script. Or you can use `objcopy` to produce linkable object files from binary files.